# java source compatibility: why does loosening a parameter type break it?

Tags: java, backwards-compatibility

Suppose we have a method like so:

```
public void foo (String input) {...}
```

We publish this. Then, later, we change it to:

```
public void foo (Object input) {...}
```

Now, I understand that this could break binary compatibility — some old bytecode could be referencing the old method, with the old signature, and it would not know at runtime to look for the newer, more loosely-typed method.

(at least I think that's the reason it is problematic)

But there is also a notion of "source compatibility", which I am getting from [sigtest](https://docs.oracle.com/javame/test-tools/sigtest/2_2/sigtest2_2_usersguide.pdf) — see section 2.2.2.

Source compatibility, it says, is a *stricter* check than binary compatibility.

But in my example above, I think any code that compiled with the old method would compile with the new method, too. So in that sense, it is "source compatible" even though it is not binary compatible, and in that sense source compatibility is *weaker* than binary compatibility.

Or am I wrong in my example?
Is there Java source that will fail to recompile when that change is made?

Comment: What if there's also a `foo(CharSequence)` overload in your class too? (Or any of the supertypes of `String`) Sure, in many cases there won't be; but it was probably decided that it's just simpler to outright forbid it than to have all the potential breakages.

Comment: It also depends on *what* you're doing with the string inside the method, if you're calling String-methods on it - it will break compilation

Comment: @alfasin: the methods in the example are the API (you can imagine they're in an `interface` that is given to users). The clients' calling code doesn't get to see what's inside the method body, so that should not matter.

Comment: "Mutual source compatibility" is not only checking that your source code compiles, it checks it against client code that uses it making sure the change didn't break it.

Comment: @alfasin: Actually, I am only interested in the latter — maintaining backwards compatibility. Using `sigtest` with the `-B` flag still reports my example as an error, though. This despite the fact that if I actually write some Java code that compiles against the old version, it also successfully compiles against the new version. Yet that's still called backwards-incompatible, somehow...